# Windows 10 nearly 100% memory used

Tags: memory

For a long time, my PC has gradually slowed in games, I've left it running days and weeks. I always figured it's just 'one of those things', stuff piling up, as I ran more things. A reboot seemed to fix it for a while.

Recently, it seemed worse. And now a reboot isn't helping; not running other programs, like games I might have launchers running the backgroud, Steam, Chrome - even not running those didn't help. For example, in a game it was bad performance stuttering constantly.

I took a look at task manager, and it showed 95-97% memory used. I rebooted, and 'clean', it still immediately showed 97% memory used. The biggest memory use it showed was malwarebytes at about 75MB. Nothing to explain it.

I was advised to run "resmon", and it showed the same thing, but it was noted that PIDs were high, and that there have been problems with Malwarebytes running a lot of zombie processes filling memory.

I tried to disable malwarebytes in services, but it gets a popup 'access denied'. I exited malwarebytes as a first test to see if it had an effect, it didn't. So I rebooted.

On reboot, despite changing malwarebytes to disabled not working, it didn't start. But the situation is the same, memory used 97%-99%, biggest process was 'Windows Explorer' at 47MB (not sure what that is, I don't run the browser). I could post task manager/resmon screenshots if there's a way to upload them (file sharing site if needed but haven't had them work well).

Resmon had a couple windows/charts for memory usage and 'hard faults'.

After the reboot, both went from black/zero, to all green/100% at once and stayed there.

Basic configuration is i7-4790K, 16GB RAM, SSD boot drive with 150GB free, 6TB hard drive with a bit over 300GB free.

Comment: Run memtest86.exe (use Rufus to make a bootable USB).  Run the drive manufacturer's drive test app.

Comment: Check the SMART attributes of your disk.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager's memory details page.  You need to "expand" Task Manager to full mode to access this page.